# Get the URL of an organization from its Org ID with sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I've seen similar questions asked but none of the answers provide an SFDX solution and I'm really hoping there is one.

I have an organization ID, but I work with several orgs. I cannot for my life remember the username to login to that organization. I tried doing the forgot-password-flow with every login we have ***but*** not all of them send me the reset email (and I have no idea where those emails are going).

Is there a way with SFDX I can pass in an org ID and get back the URL or maybe even a list of users? The answers to the similar questions are old and I'm hoping by now Salesforce has provided a solution to this seemingly common problem that doesn't involve getting in touch with technical support.

Answer (score 0):

You know what, I think I figured it out. The command

```
> sfdx force:org:list
```

Lists orgs and their usernames. Assuming you've worked with the org with SFDX before, you should be able to just grep the org ID and see the appropriate login. From there you just login with the username (hopefully you know the password and the user's email is yours) and check the URL from there.